# Seleccionar un lista multiple de Android con cabeceras

Tags: android, listview

Buenas tardes chicos, tengo una duda sobre Android. Consiste en que quiero hacer un listView con selección múltiple, de forma que cuando selecciones un ítem cambie el fondo. Eso lo tengo resuelto, pero también quiero que esa lista múltiple tenga cabeceras, ya que es una lista de actividades y estas actividades están agrupadas por categorías.El problema esta en que cuando las agrupo por actividades ya deja de seleccionarse.

Por si es útil, yo hago primero la lista seleccionable sin cabeceras y creo un actividades_item con un "android:background="@drawable/selector" donde selector es un archivo en drawable que hace la funcionalidad de cambiar el color según la propiedad de seleccionado o no seleccionado.

Cuando creo la lista con la cabecera lo que hago es crear el objeto Categoria y  creo un Adaptador personalizado para las actividades donde el getView es este:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;

    Object o = (Object)items.get(position);
    if(o instanceof Actividad2) {

        if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLan) == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actividades_item, null);


        }

        Actividad2 actividad = (Actividad2) o;

        final CheckedTextView nombreActividad = (CheckedTextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtLan);
        nombreActividad.setText(actividad.getNombre());

        final String[] pulsado = {"no"};

        nombreActividad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){



            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

             /* ESTA COMENTADO
                if(pulsado[0].equals("no")){
                    pulsado[0] = "si";
                    nombreActividad.setTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                    nombreActividad.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);

                }else{
                    pulsado[0] = "no";
                    nombreActividad.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                    nombreActividad.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                }
              FIN DEL COMENTARIO  */
            }

        });


    }else{

        if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHeader) == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categoria_item, null);


        }

        Categoria categoria = (Categoria)o;
        TextView nombreCategoria = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewHeader);
        nombreCategoria.setText(categoria.getNombre());

    }



    return vi;
}
```

Como se puede ver, cuando es una categoría  se usa un layout y cuando es una actividad se utiliza otro, y en la parte comentada he intentado que cuando se selecciona una actividad pues se cambie la vista de color. pero en ese caso se me repite y se cambia de color en varios items.

Por último comentar que cuando lleno la lista es mediante un for voy haciendo un bucle para recoger las categorías y luego dentro otro for para recoger las actividades de cada categoría (no se si el for tendrá que ver con el problema de que se seleccionen varios items).

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas por adelantado.

Comment: Quizas deberia usar un recyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás seteando la funcionalidad para las primeras lineas con:

```
if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLan) == null)
```

y

```
if (convertView == null || convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHeader) == null)
```

Esas lineas son "true" al principio pero luego de las primeras lineas ya deja de ser null y por lo tanto no se actualiza tu row dependiendo el caso. 
Mi solución rápida sería que la quites en los dos casos...

Y por ultimo, yo te recomiendo en principio que estudies RecyclerView, al principio puede que no lo quieras, pero cuando lo adoptes es 10 veces mas flexible y ágil.

Comment: Pero si las quito al principio son null, entonces me da error de NullException....... Respecto recyclerView voy a verlo a ver.